# Condition saved inside a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to save the result of a condition inside a variable in Bash ?

Something like:

```
IS_DEV=$[[ "$ENV" = "$DEV" ]]
```

With `ENV=$1` and `DEV="development"`.

and then being able to use it several time:

```
if $IS_DEV; then
    ...
fi
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate it only once and store the result, or evaluate it every time?

Comment: `[[ "$ENV" -eq $DEV ]]; IS_DEV=$?` ought to do it, to evaluate once.

Comment: Don't **ever** use the name  `ENV` for your own purposes. Any value stored in `ENV` is treated as the name of a script to run on initialization by `/bin/sh` (and `sh` is used by `system()`, Python's `shell=True`, and lots of other internal bits inside your system). Avoiding that kind of conflict is part of why POSIX specifies that only all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the OS or shell, whereas variables with at least one lowercase letter are safe for application use.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace (as setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: @robert, this is just as relevant to bash on Windows or other non-UNIX platforms; there's no point to the extra tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code should be stored in functions, not variables; [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into details on the perils of doing otherwise.

```
# aside: don't use upper-case names for your own variables. ENV, specifically, is reserved
# per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html
is_dev() { [[ $ENV = "$DEV" ]]; }

if is_dev; then
```

By contrast, if you want to store a result:

```
if [[ $ENV = "$DEV" ]]; then is_dev=1; else is_dev=0; fi

if (( is_dev )); then ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !